# Constrain Fit to make a fit that remains positive over the range of my independent variable

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, say I have the following data.

```
{{100, 1.5157*10^-3}, {200, 1.4556*10^-4}, {300, 2.8538*10^-5}, 
 {400, 7.5323*10^-6}, {500, 2.3853*10^-6}, {600, 8.3798*10^-7}}
```

When I attempt to use the `Fit` command (to any order of x) the result always allows for the y value to be negative at some x.  Is there anyway I can add a constraint that will prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Clear[a, b, c];
lst = {{100, 1.5157*10^-3}, {200, 1.4556*10^-4}, {300, 
    2.8538*10^-5}, {400, 7.5323*10^-6}, {500, 2.3853*10^-6}, {600, 
    8.3798*10^-7}};

model = a*Exp[-b*x];
ff = FindFit[lst, {model, {a > 0, b > 0}}, {{a, 0.002}, b}, x]
Show[{

  ListPlot[lst, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.015]}],
  Plot[(model /. ff), {x, 40, 600}]
  }]
```

The result is

```
(*  {a -> 0.0110629, b -> 0.0200711}  *)
```

and the fitting is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to apply constraints to a list of data that does not take a exponential form?

Comment: @user16104 Whenever you do data fitting, you have to have some model that agrees with your underlying understanding of the data. In your case this is positivity. But there are infinitely many different models one could choose, and I think it should be up to you modify Alexei's answer to accommodate any other expectations you might have.

Comment: @user16104 I agree with each word of Jens. I write this comment just to explain the same a bit less concisely. The trick I applied is typical for physical problems where concentration is fitted. The concentration is always positive analogously to your case, and is often represented in the exponential form. This motivates to look for an exponential fitting. In general the best fit should agree with the internal logic of your problem. If such logic is available, it may give a hint of the functional form of the model. I do not know this logic, but you do. So it is up to you to find a model.

Comment: @user16104: Continuation. The logic I have in mind is the same as the one I used assuming that your variable is the concentration and looking for the exponential fitting. It may also happen that there is no internal logic at all, or it is not known. I that case one usually takes the simplest model possible agreeing with your condition. For example, the function `1/(1+x^2)`is always positive, or `1/(1+Pn(x))^2`, where `Pn(x)`is a polynomial. And you may think about lots of other positive functions. Have fun!